# How to calculate the resolution of an undistorted image?

Tags: opencv, ros

An undistorted image typically have lower resolution than the original image due to non-uniform distribution of pixels and (usually) the cropping of the black edges.  (See below as an example)

[image]

So given the camera calibration parameters, e.g. in ROS format

```
image_width: 1600
image_height: 1200
camera_name: camera1
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1384.355466887268, 0, 849.4355708515795, 0, 1398.17734010913, 604.5570699746268, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [0.0425049914802741, -0.1347528158561486, -0.0002287009852930437, 0.00641133892300999, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [1379.868041992188, 0, 860.3000889574832, 0, 0, 1405.926879882812, 604.3997819099422, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

How would one calculate the final resolution of the undistorted rectified image?

Comment: This is described here: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#undistortion

Answer (score 0):

From Fruchtzwerg's comment, the following will give the effective ROI of the undistorted image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
mtx = np.array([
    [1384.355466887268, 0, 849.4355708515795],
    [ 0, 1398.17734010913, 604.5570699746268],
    [0, 0, 1]])
dist = np.array([0.0425049914802741, -0.1347528158561486, -0.0002287009852930437, 0.00641133892300999, 0])

cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (1600, 1200), 1)
```